# Como mandar um select feito por uma StringBuffer para uma classe

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Eu não sei como mandar um *select* feito na minha classe DatabaseHelper e mandá-lo para uma classe publica, aí a partir disso fazer com que meu código funcione normalmente.

Minha classe DatabaseHelper e no final etá o *select*:

```
class AddressBookDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Forca.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // constructor
    public AddressBookDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // creates the contacts table when the database is created
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // SQL for creating the contacts table
        final String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + Contact.TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                        Contact._ID + " integer primary key, " +
                        Contact.COLUMN_WORD + " TEXT, " +
                        Contact.COLUMN_TIP + " TEXT);";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE); // create the contacts table
    }

    // normally defines how to upgrade the database when the schema changes
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

/* SELECT RANDOM */
    private void Exemplo(){
        List<String> dados = new ArrayList();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT palavra FROM palavrasforca";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do{
                String palavra = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("palavra"));
                dados.add(palavra);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        //aqui dados terá todos os valores do banco
    }

}
```

E agora a classe para onde quero mandar:

```
public class Palavras {

    private String[] palavras = new String[] {/* Gravar os valores da coluna aqui*/};

    public Palavras() {

    }

    public String sorteio() {
        String palavraSorteada = palavras[(int)(random()*palavras.length)];

        return palavraSorteada;
    }

    public static double random() {
        Random r = new Random();

        return r.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

Gostaria de saber como eu poderia gravar os dados do *select* na private `String[] palavras = new String[] {};`

Answer (score 0):

Você criar um set para a propriedade ou alterar ela para public por exemplo

```
public class Palavras {
    public String[] palavras = new String[] 
}
```

e você chamaria desta maneira

```
public void Exemplo2(){
   Palavras palavras = new Palavras(); //instancia o objeto
   palavras.palavras = new String[] {"exemplo1", "exemplo2"} //aqui você trocaria pelo array que você quer passar
}
```

você pode fazer via construtor também (que é mais recomendado)

```
public class Palavras {

    private String[] palavras = new String[] {/* Gravar os valores da coluna aqui*/};

    public Palavras(String[] arrayPalavras) {
        this.palavras = arrayPalavras;
    }

    public String[] getPalavras(){
       return palavras;
    } 
}
```

e usar deste jeito:

```
public void Exemplo2(){
       String dados = new String[] {"exemplo1", "exemplo2"}
       Palavras palavras = new Palavras(dados); //instancia o objeto //aqui é obrigado a passar "dados" para construir a classe Palavras
       String dados2 = palavras.getPalavras(); //'dados2' contém mesmo que 'dados'

    }
```